# Magnific Popup to open in Mobile with fullscreen

Tags: mobile, fullscreen, magnific-popup

First question: How can I open the magnific popup window 100% height and width of the mobile screen.

Second question is I want to add loader image before the ajax popup is loaded.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax-popup-1').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax: {
  cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur' }
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeOnBgClick: false,
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    });

});

In CSS I added
.mfp-ajax-cur {background: url('images/loader.gif') no-repeat scroll center center #000000;}

But it is not working, is anything wrong here?

Thanks, 
Babar